# Using multiple strategies in Passport, how can I find the strategy being used?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I've got a REST API built with Node.js/Express, and my endpoints are protected using either a username/password combination (HTTP Basic Authentication, with [passport-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-http)) or bearer token (HTTP Bearer Authentication, with [passport-http-bearer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-http-bearer)).

This is how I use `passport.authenticate` in my router:

```
passport.authenticate(['basic', 'bearer'], { session: false });
```

I'd like to be able to determine which strategy was used for the request from within my routes (so I could, for example, limit the access of token requests).

Does Passport provide a way to do this? If not, is there a workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: If I recall correctly I ended up setting `req.user.token` for token authentication, then checked if it's defined later down the middleware chain

Comment: OK fair enough. Thought there might be something exposed by passport in the request but it doesn't look like it :(